# C++: Datatype of a "number constant"

Tags: c++, types, compilation

I had in mind the numeric constant in C++ (and also in C) have a datatype assigned.
When these constants are an operand the datatype can influence the result and the result's datatype.

I know the datatype depends on the constant itself like `5` or `5.0` `5.0f` **and** it depends on the architecture/compiler.

But I don't know the rules exactly and searched a lot and it seems I didn't get the right keywords.

I did something like that:

`inline unsigned long __DWORD(byte b0, byte b1, byte b2, byte b3) { return (unsigned long)((b0 << 24) + (b1 << 16) + (b2 << 8) + (b3 << 0)); }`

and while it worked perfectly on a SAMD21 (32bit) it didn't work on atmega (8bit).

`inline unsigned long __DWORD(byte b0, byte b1, byte b2, byte b3) { return (unsigned long)(((unsigned long)b0 << 24) + ((unsigned long)b1 << 16) + ((unsigned long)b2 << 8) + ((unsigned long)b3 << 0)); }`
that worked. And I'm sure casting the right operand would also have worked.

how can I know whats the default datatyp of a numeric constant is? Is the behaviour defined?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, I think the word you're looking for is "[literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)". I'll try to find a better resource, but that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) is what I was thinking. That will give you the idea of how C++ suffixes work, and the types associated with each of them.

Comment: literal, yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you're conflating the concept of "data type" with the *size* of the underlying type -- which are two different things.

The *type* of an expression is fixed and well-defined in C++.

- All literals have a fixed, well-defined underlying type, whether they are [integral literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), [floating literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal), [boolean literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bool_literal), [character literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal), or even [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

  - For example: `5` is an `int` literal, `5.0` is a `double` literal, `5.0f` is a `float` literal.
- All fundamental types may follow [implicit conversions and integral promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) in certain scenarios. This is what lets you write code like `unsigned int x = 5`, which assigns an `int` literal to an `unsigned int` type variable.

The *size* of a type, on the other hand, is **implementation-defined**. It depends entirely on the compiler (most-often, on the target architecture).

The C++ language gives us few guarantees on the size of these types<sup>[[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)]</sup>, which makes it unreliable for portability to use these types while expecting a specific size.

In general, you're better off using the [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) header types for fixed-with integrals.

For example, your `__DWORD` example could be written:

```cpp
inline std::uint32_t __DWORD(std::uint8_t b0, std::uint8_t b1, std::uint8_t b2, std::uint8_t b3) 
{ 
    return static_cast<std::uint32_t>(
      (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(b0) << 24) + 
      (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(b1) << 16) + 
      (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(b2) << 8) + 
      (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(b3) << 0)
    );
}
```

The reason the cast to `uint32_t` is needed for `b0`,`b1`,`b2`, and `b3` is because the resultant type of a shift operations is always the type on the **left-hand side** of the operation. So if `sizeof(b0)` is `1`, then `b0 << 24` will shift all data out of `b0` because it exceeds 8 bits. Casting to `uint32_t` ensures that the result of the shift will fit into the resultant type.

So to be clear: The *type* of the expression does not depend on the compiler or architecture; just the size of the underlying type.

---

On an unrelated note, any identifier containing two double underscores (`__`), or starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (`_D`) are reserved for the implementation, and should not be used. Your `__DWORD` function should probable be renamed something like `make_uint32(...)` instead

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed explanation! It is very helpful